# How to randomly select buttons in android?

Tags: java, android, random

I wanted to know how to randomly select a button in android. Like for example there got 4 button, I want the application to randomly choose a button from them and do some actions to it. Here is my code:

```
Button start;
ImageButton btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5;
Random random = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_memory);
    start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    start.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    btn2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    btn3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    btn4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);

}

ImageButton[] all= {btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4};

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == start)
    {
        btn5 = all[random.nextInt(all.length)];
        btn5.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

If I change to this it work perfectly but then it will only be btn1 and not randomly select.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == start)
    {
        btn5 = btn1;
        btn5.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is problem ? do you get any Error?

Comment: you need the **btn5** to be perform some actions when the **start** button is clicked

Comment: when I click the button, the application crashes.

Comment: You can check like `v.getId() == R.id.button1` if you didn't getting error

Comment: it seems like **btn5** is not assigned to any of the button

Comment: @PratikButani He was not adding the listeners to the **ImageButton** 's

Comment: @user3153613 Running Solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20883712/1318946

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`all` must be set **after** you have set `btn1` etc: Otherwise it'll be an array of `null`s.

```
    btn1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    btn2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    btn3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    btn4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    all= {btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4}; //here
}

ImageButton[] all; //not here
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to place this line inside your `onCreate()` method:

```
all= {btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4};
```

As it is now:

```
ImageButton[] all= {btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4};
```

It runs in the contractor time where all the buttons are null. Than in the onCreate you assign the buttons for new variables, how ever this does not change ImageButton. Alternativly you could wrote:

```
ImageButton[0] = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
ImageButton[1] = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
ImageButton[2] = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
ImageButton[3] = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
```

Comment: but if I put
`all= {btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4};`
It got error. I can`t put
`ImageButton[] all;` only

Comment: @user3153613 Copy past weston answer. We are saying the same thing, I just explain why.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-numbers-in-a-range-with-java)

check the above reference for generating random number then use

```
switch(number)
{
case 1:
button.performClick()

.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do this way

```
 ImageButton[] all= {btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4};

 Random rand = new Random();
 ImageButton randomBtn = all[rand.nextInt(all.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is following code which i have run currently:

```
    Button start;
    ImageButton btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5;
    Random random;

    int[] all;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        random = new Random();

        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        start.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton01);
        btn2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton02);
        btn3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton03);
        btn4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton04);

        all = new int[]{R.id.ImageButton01,R.id.ImageButton02,R.id.ImageButton03,R.id.ImageButton04};
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1)
        {
            int id = all[random.nextInt(all.length)];
            findViewById(id).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
```